# Force next interface key to have the same type as the previous key

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
interface X {
 a: any;
 b: the same as a;
}
```

Can I in some way force `X.b` to have the same type as the `X.a`?

an example:

```
fun(data: X) {
   ...
}
```

`fun({a: 'text', b: 'otherText'})` <-- fine, because `b` is of type string as `a`.
`fun({a: 'text', b: false})` <-- error because `b` doesn't match `a` type.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your looking for is something called generics.

eg.

```
interface X<T> {
 a: T;
 b: T;
}

function fun(data: X<string>) {
}

fun({ a: "abc", b: "one" }); //ok
fun({ a: "abc", b: false }); //fail
```

Comment: Well, I knew about generics interfaces but  In fact I have a bit more complexed object than in above example. a and b are deeply nested and I wouldn't like to cast the whole interface :\

Comment: @elzoy Post a more complete example, otherwise Keith's answer it the most obvious answer to your question.